# update table where column name is set as variable mysql

Tags: mysql, variables, sql-update

I am creating a mysql statement that should update a table, but instead of setting a column name to be equal to some value the normal way, I decided to make it dynamic, for example  instead of:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = 'a value';
```

I use a variable. In this case:

```
SET @column = 'mycolumn';
UPDATE mytable SET @column = 'a value';
```

This returns a syntax error message when I execute the update statement. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
set @query = 'UPDATE mytable SET @column = ''a value''';
set @query = replace(@query, '@column', 'col_name');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```